# How To Display Tooltip for TextBox While Entering the Text in that in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How To Display  Tooltip for  TextBox While Entering the Text in that in asp.net .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

intially tooltip is display:none

```
$("input[id$=tbMyTextbox]").focus(function() {
   $("div[id$=tooltip]").show();
});

$("input[id$=tbMyTextbox]").blur(function() {
   $("div[id$=tooltip]").hide();
});
```

check this also works : http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/