# How To Force The TooTip For A TextBox in asp.net When entering Some Text in textbox?

Tags: asp.net

i Want To Set a Tooltip For a TextBox in asp.net when entering Some Text in that textbox.

Comment: Do you want to set it up front or must it reflect the same text as you typed in?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Display Tooltip for TextBox While Entering the Text in that in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083725/how-to-display-tooltip-for-textbox-while-entering-the-text-in-that-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

register following javascript function:

```
function changeTooltipText(control){
    isNetscape=(document.layers); 
    keyCode = (isNetscape)? keyStroke.which : event.keyCode; 
    newChar = String.fromCharCode(keyCode); 
    if(control!=null){
        control.title=control.value + newChar;
    }
}
```

register the onkeypress-event on the textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" onkeypress="changeTooltipText(this)" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```